# pdfbox want to print A4 pages to LETTER paper

Tags: printing, pdfbox

Using PdfBox 1.8.x version when I want to print a pdf document which has A4 sized pages, the printer do not print the document on A4 papers because it is waiting to enter LETTER papers. Don't understand this...

How could I print A4 documents on A4 papers? Or globally, how could I say to the printer, that it have to scale the document to A4 and do not wait to enter any other paper?

Thanks,
Laci

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: Maybe a version problem? I use 1.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure the PDPage() objects created in your code to be A4 size? It can be done in the following way when you create them:

```
PDPage newpage = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4)
```

Comment: The document is created elsewhere, I just want to print it out.